# Oauth Login for Google Drive: Cloudn't sign you in, This browser or app may not be secure

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

We are working on a desktop application that can log in to Google drive.
OAuth has been approved.

We are having cases of some of the users can login into google drive successfully.
But some of the users are kept getting the following message:
[image]

We are able to get the google login page. When we hit login in with google drive.
Here is a list of API is called:
[image]

When we enter the user email and hit next. It checks users email with the following REQUEST:
[image]

Details break down:

POST /_/lookup/accountlookup?hl=en&_reqid=**REQID**&rt=j HTTP/1.1

Request Referer:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/identifier?client_id=**CLIENTID**&redirect_uri=**REDIRECTURI**&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&response_type=code&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

We tried the settings online about:

1. disable two-way authentication
2. ON less secure app

But one of them works.
We also tried to follow [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#libraries) and [enter link description here](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/blob/master/OAuthDesktopApp/OAuthDesktopApp/MainWindow.xaml.cs), but haven't figure out the issues successfully.

Comment: Here is a thread related to your issue: https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/22873505/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-when-trying-to-sign-in-with-google-on-desktop-apps?hl=en

Comment: @jasonandmonte Thanks, but I did go over the that earlier, not working still

Comment: Are you able to modify the user agent? I had the same issue as you show and passing 'Chrome' as the user agent allowed us to bypass the block.

Comment: @jasonandmonte "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36" -- this is the agent we using. Did you get the issue fixed successfully?

Comment: Yes, switching the user agent to 'Chrome' has bypassed the block for our application for over year now.